# matplotlib - pie chart label customize with percentage

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I would like to draw a pie chart with label and percentage, current example put percentage inside pie chart. how can I move the percentage string out and append it at the end of each label?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['MemFree', 717412],
    ['Buffers', 17224],
      ['Inactive',3958020],
      ['Slab',    565396],
      ['PageTables',122968],
    ['Unknow',+ 2448624]
]
df = pd.DataFrame()
idx = 0
for i in data:
    df.loc[idx,'name'] = i[0]
    df.loc[idx,'value'] = i[1]
    idx += 1
print(df)

fig, ax1=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10))

ax1.pie(df['value'],labels=df['name'],autopct='%1.1f%%',counterclock=False,startangle=90)

plt.show()
```

current output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`ax.pie` returns the wedges and lists of text objects for the labels and the percentages.  You could loop through the labels and percentages, and append the percentage text to the label text. And then remove the percentage text objects.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = [['MemFree', 717412],
        ['Buffers', 17224],
        ['Inactive', 3958020],
        ['Slab', 565396],
        ['PageTables', 122968],
        ['Unknow', 2448624]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'value'])
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10))

_wedges, labels, percentages = ax1.pie(df['value'], labels=df['name'], autopct='%1.1f%%', counterclock=False,
                                       startangle=90)

for label, percentage in zip(labels, percentages):
    label.set_text(label.get_text() + '\n' + percentage.get_text())
    percentage.remove()

plt.show()
```

[image: pie chart with percentages outside]